# Write JSON to a file. But how do you read it back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I write JSON to my file :

```
NSData *jsonData = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeObject:dictionary error:&error];
[jsonData writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"file.json"]] atomically:YES];
```

But how do i read it back?

I tried load the file into NSData, and convert to a NSDictionary like so

```
    // uses toll-free bridging for data into CFDataRef and CFPropertyList into NSDictionary
CFPropertyListRef plist =  CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef)data,
                                                           kCFPropertyListImmutable,
                                                           NULL);
// we check if it is the correct type and only return it if it is
if ([(id)plist isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    return [(NSDictionary *)plist autorelease];
}
else
{
    // clean up ref
    CFRelease(plist);
    return nil;
}
```

But it crashed because i think NSData is not a plist.

Has CJSONSerializer got a method to extract the data from the file and help me convert it to a dictionary?

Thanks,
-Code

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 5 look into NSJSONSerializer.  It has methods for going both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a serializer to convert an object to JSON, and *de*serializer for the opposite direction. And indeed TouchJSON has a CJSONDeserializer class:

```
[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:data error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CJSONDeserializer` for parsing, `CJSONSerializer` is only for generating JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSJSONSerialization to read JSON file to NSData, then convert to nsdictionary as well.

```
-(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:(NSString*)fileLocation
{

   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileLocation stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[fileLocation pathExtension]];
   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
   id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                            options:kNilOptions error:&error];
   if (error != nil) return nil;
   return result;

}
```